# Galaxy Nexus ICS Does't remember wifi Passwords - ICS 4.2.2

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean

Anybody else have this issue?  It's freaking annoying as every time i revisit somewhere and want to use their wifi, i have to get the password and enter it in again.

Any suggestions on how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the wpa_supplicant file is corrupted. If you are rooted, you might be able to use an app like Titanium Backup to wipe the data for it. If you aren't rooted, I am not sure what all you can wipe. You can try and wipe the Settings database (Settings -> Apps -> All -> Settings -> Wipe Data, which might include the file, but I don't know for sure (this will obviously erase all your Android settings)..

But you should be able to fix it by performing a Factory Reset/Data Wipe (Settings -> Backup and Reset -> Factory Data Reset). Google should remember your apps and automatically install them once you type your password back in, and all your sdcard content should stay untouched.

Comment: Thanks for that... i'll try a factory reset when i have an internet connection fast enough to redownload everything.  Sucks to have to set everything up again though :(

Comment: I did the wipe data on the settings app, and that seems to have fixed it.  Thanks so much Bassmadrigal :)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @Gregorius You don't need internet connection to backup, reset, restore, you can do it with adb as in the guide here: http://www.howtogeek.com/125375/how-to-create-a-full-android-phone-or-tablet-backup-without-rooting-or-unlocking-your-device/

Comment: @NoBugs, that wouldn't help, because it would back up his issue and then restore it. He'd be left with the same problem when he did this.

Comment: @bassmadrigal It absolutely helps - I fixed a Dell Android tablet with this never-remembering-wifi problem with backup, reset and restore.

Comment: @NoBugs, it had to be related to something else. If you back up a corrupted file, erase it, and then restore the corrupted file, how is that file magically fixed?

Comment: @bassmadrigal From what I understand adb backup backs up all apps and their settings. There is no setting in any app for Never-remember-wifi-accesspoints, it's likely a system file or glitch on last update or... who knows, if you don't have root.

Comment: The wpa_supplicant.conf file resides on the data partition. Unless it doesn't back up your saved Wi-Fi networks (I've never tried it since I've always been rooted), that file will be backed up as well. If it is the file that's corrupted, using adb backup and restore won't help.